# Make a div stick to the right edge of the parent and overlap others in the parent

Tags: html, css

I need to place a div stick to the right edge of its parent div and when re-sizing the browser window, it should overlap other elements in the same parent and they should be hidden.

This image tells the story

[image]

Please note that, I don't want that div to have fixed position. It should scroll just like others and the elements (texts or whatever) should be under it. Just like the attached image.

I tried the following code but, it made the red div stick to the edge of its grandparent.

```
.redarea{
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
}
```

What's the way of getting this done ?

Comment: Try `position: fixed; float: right;`. `position: absolute;` will only work if you have specified the top, left and right attributes.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: fyi, position absolute is relative to its closes position relative parent

Comment: @AbdulAhmad and others Thank you! you opened my eyes. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This one does exactly what you want

```css
#parent{
  border:1px solid red; 
  width:100%; 
  height:60px; 
  position:relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#rightchild{
  top: 0;
  width:100px; 
  right:0; 
  bottom: 0;
  background:red; 
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" style="">
 <p>This area is getting hidden This area is getting hidden This area is getting hiddenThis area is getting hidden</p>
 <div id="rightchild">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TharinduLucky well i just deleted my answer with the update of white-space ... , then i guess i put it on line again ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus Thanks! Yeah, `white-space: nowrap;`  is the one I too missed. :)

Comment: @GCyrillus Don't forget the `overflow: hidden` to avoid scrollbar ;)

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the easiest way to do it imo.
Give your outer box a padding on the right side, and let the inner box fill up the padding by giving it the same width and positioning it absolutely to the right.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      div.outer{
        width: 90%;
        height: 30px;
        padding-right: 30px;
        position: relative;
        border: 2px solid #ddd;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      div.inner{
        width: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: red;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you're not familiar with positioning absolute/relative, I can elaborate on that in an edit.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone, using all of your help, I managed to write this code. Let me know if it's illegal.

```
#parent{
  border:1px solid red; 
  width:100%; 
  height:60px; 
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#rightchild{
  width:100px; 
  right:0; 
  height:60px; 
  background:red; 
  position:absolute;
}

p{
   float:left;
}

<div id="parent" style="">
    <p>This area is getting hidden This area is getting hidden This area is getting hiddenThis area is getting hidden</p>
    <div id="rightchild">
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xfnwa45d/2/)**

Comment: well text is still hidding behind and container doesn't grow when text breaks into lines, i do not get anymore what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted. Text should be hiding behind the red div. I just want the text to be hidden when it breaks in to lines. Only a some part should be visible. Don't want to see the other lines but the first line.

Comment: okay, then overflow:hidden might be usefull too ? when it goes underneat #parent

Comment: Yeah I forgot that too. And updated the code and fiddle.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't even need a float on it. You would just need to have:

`position: fixed;
right:0;`

You may also need to specify a z-index on it depending how you coded it. If it's underneath instead of on top, do a:

`z-index:14;` or something of the like.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use `display:inline-block` too. see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/sasc1a7h/

keep in mind the `calc()` css property is not supported by all browsers yet (especially older ones)

Answer (score 0):

To keep text on a single line: `white-space:nowrap` .

display should help you here to avoid the use of `position`: either table or flex :

```css
.flex {
  display: flex
}
.full {
  white-space:nowrap;
  }
.flex .full {
  flex: 1;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.table p {
  display: table-cell;
}
p {
  border: solid;
}
.cds {
  padding: 0.25em;
  background: tomato;
  width: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <p class="full"> text to spray in flex display  text to spray in flex display  text to spray in flex display </p>
  <p class="cds">condense</p>
</div>
<div class="table">
  <p class="full"> text to spray in table display text to spray in table display text to spray in table display</p>
  <p class="cds">condense</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is fine but the text doesn't go underneath the red-colored div. Instead it just go to next line. Which cause change the height of the parent div.

Comment: @TharinduLucky okay, so this text should stand first in html and float:right; (demo added to answer)

Comment: No my friend, text shouldn't get flip to the next line even though there's no room for it. It should just be hidden. Like this...  https://jsfiddle.net/xfnwa45d/

Comment: @TharinduLucky ah okay, then we talk about white-space ;) ?